# Slim php framework, change keys of multidimensional

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, alias, slim

I Have 2 example of url like below

```
http://localhost:8000/ijazah?filter[id_prodi][<exact>]=1010102&filter[angkatan][<exact>]=2014

http://localhost:8000/ijazah?filter[id_prodi]=1010102&filter[angkatan]=2014
```

what I have done in Controller is

```
//get parameter
$query = $this->request->getQueryParams();
//validate parameter
$filter = is_array($query['filter']) ? $query['filter'] : [];
//change keys
$filter = $this->transformer->changeKeys($filter, IjazahTransformer::$alias);
//testing
vardump($filter);
```

When I use 2nd url the result is what I have expected
but when I use 1st url the keys changed but values was empty.

I doubt I aliased with single dimension alias.

below is a part of IjazahTransformer Class

```
class IjazahTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
    public static $alias = [
        'angkatan' => 'ANGKATAN',
        'id_prodi' => 'IDPRODI',
    ];
}
```

and below is the result both of url

> Result First URL

```
array (size=2)
  'IDPRODI' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'ANGKATAN' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

> Result Second URL

```
array (size=2)
  'IDPRODI' => string '1010102' (length=7)
  'ANGKATAN' => string '2014' (length=4)
```

> What I want to use the first url but it is listed with its value not with empty value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the changeKeys method don't run your expected. If you can change TransformerAbstract or you do it like below. Or you can override IjazahTransformer

```html
public function changeKeys($filter, $alias)
{
    foreach ($filter as $key=>$v) {
        $newFilter[$alias[$key]] = array_values($v)[0];
    }
    return $newFilter;
}
```

Result:

```html
array(2) {
  ["IDPRODI"]=> string(7) "1010102"
  ["ANGKATAN"]=> string(4) "2014"
}
```